# Segmentation Fault in Binary Tree Program

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a binary tree to accept strings from a file.  When I run my main file I get a segmentation fault.  I've run gdb and it's telling me the problem is at my while loop.  I can't seem to figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "BiTree.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct TreeNode *root = 0;
    char string[20] = {0};
    int ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(!feof(inFile)) {
        do {
            ch = fgetc(inFile);
            if(isalpha(ch)) {
                string[i] = ch;
            }
            i++;
        } while(isspace(ch));
        i = 0;
        insert(string, root);
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    displayTree(root);
    destroyTree(root);

    FILE *outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program using GDB to see what's causing the problem with your while loop?

Comment: No example of input data, no comments in code -- no help.

Comment: You have 2 while loops.  And why do you open & immediately close a file at the end?

Comment: I think that this line is the problem : while(isspace(ch)) it should be
while(!isspace(ch)) if I understand correct the meaning.

Comment: Yes, maybe something like `while(!isspace(ch) && i<19)`. It may be a good idea to check whether `fopen()` succeded or not. Something like `if (pFile!=NULL)
  {
    while(...){}
    fclose (pFile);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the problem with `while(isspace(ch));` that should probably be replaced with `while(!isspace(ch));` you need to add a null character at the end of your string before sending it to your `insert()` function and this function should also return a new value for the root variable:

```
string[i]= 0;
i=0;
root=insert(string,root);
```

You should also make sure that the value of i doesn't get higher than 19 in order to not overrun the length of the string buffer.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your help. I forgot I needed to null terminate my string. And apologies to everyone for my sloppiness (I posted this in a rush).